# how to install/update a package from source inside cygwin

Tags: r, cygwin

new to Cygwin. I downloaded apg-cyg and have been using it to install packages.

Recently I installed R and the current version in Cygwin packages is R.3.2.4. I wanted to install the latest R package but couldn't find a way from googling on how to do it inside Cygwin.

Is this possible to do or I just have to wait for the Cygwin packages updating their packages to the latest version? It would be nice to be able to update a package using the source file inside Cygwin..

Edit:

I should mention that I tried to install ggplot2 inside R using install.packages() and there was non-zero exit status and the installation couldn't go through.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the source using cygwin setup. Click on the mouse on the "Src?" column.

The source will be installed in `/usr/src`

[image: Cygwin source intallation]

PS: next R release 3.3.1 is in 11 days. It will be packed for cygwin if there are no build issue

Followup:
There were several build issues, it took longer than expected to build 3.3.1

https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-06/msg00056.html

Comment: thanks for the answer! however, this source will still be 3.2.4, not the latest I want to install... How do you know when the next R release will become available? Where to look for this info?

Comment: That source is the one to build the cygwin package including the script build, so it matches as version with the binary. Upstream is at `https://www.r-project.org/` .  For inquiry on cygwin you need to ask on cygwin mailing list  `https://cygwin.com/cygwin/lists.html`

Comment: oh i meant how do you know when R release 3.3.1  is in 11 days?

Comment: R project home page: "Final release is scheduled for Tuesday 2016-06-21."

Comment: i see. well, R 3.3.1 will be available for other systems but it probably won't be immediately available for cygwin.. it's the same thing i am dealing with now, cygwin doesn't update its packages as often

Comment: More than other distribution. `https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-04/msg00022.html` at least for my packages